# camera_calibration set_camera_info Service not found

Tags: calibration, stereo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to calibrate a stereo camera with camera_calibration on Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04. I have two separate webcams connected and use gscam to return the video stream. However when I want to calibrate them using camera_calibration by typing:

```
rj@rj-K55VD:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 --approximate=0.1 right:=/right/camera/image_raw left:=/left/camera/image_raw right_camera:=/right/camera left_camera:=/left/camera
```

I get the following output:

```
('Waiting for service', '/left/camera/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found
('Waiting for service', '/right/camera/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found
```

I guess it tries to look for camera_info which is published.
Rostopic list gives the following output

```
rj@rj-K55VD:~/catkin_ws$ rostopic list
/left/camera/camera_info
/left/camera/image_raw
/right/camera/camera_info
/right/camera/image_raw /rosout
/rosout_agg
```

So I do not know what the problem is or what is missing since the cameras seems to be running fine.

Just to be complete, the xml code of one of the camera launch file is

```
<launch>
  <!-- This launchfile should bring up a node that broadcasts a ros image
       transport on /webcam/image_raw -->

  <arg name="DEVICEl" default="/dev/video2"/>
  <!-- The GStreamer framerate needs to be an integral fraction -->
  <arg name="FPS" default="30/1"/>
  <arg name="PUBLISH_FRAME" default="false"/>

  <node ns="left" name="gscam_driver_v4l" pkg="gscam" type="gscam" output="screen">
    <param name="camera_name" value="default"/>
    <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini"/>
    <param name="gscam_config" value="v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICEl) ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=$(arg FPS) ! ffmpegcolorspace"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="/v4l_frame_l"/>
    <param name="sync_sink" value="true"/>
  </node>

  <node if="$(arg PUBLISH_FRAME)" name="v4l_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="1 2 3 0 -3.141 0 /world /v4l_frame 10"/>
</launch>
```

I have an identical launch file for the right camera, only with some of the node names a bit different to avoid confusions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200154/camera_calibration-set_camera_info-service-not-found/) by [Mesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21251/mesus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

set_camera_info is a service, not a topic. Use rosservice to see it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21251/mesus/) on 2014-12-30**:
Thanks. I'm still quite the noob in ROS so I didn't know that.
Typing rosservice showed me where set_camera_info was (it didn't have *camera* in its path)

So leaving out *camera* from the command did the trick:

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2016-01-04**:
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x6 --square 0.025 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**1.**  Use --no-service-check to run calibration

$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 --no-service-check --approximate=0.1 right:=/right/camera/image_raw left:=/left/camera/image_raw right_camera:=/right/camera left_camera:=/left/camera

**2.** ('Waiting for service', '/left/camera/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found

Since it is a service, it cannot be found in topic list. You can find the services provided by a node under its info.
$ rosnode info /left/camera

---

Originally posted by [Sumit Dey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27553/sumit-dey/) with karma: 83 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For melodic, I simply removed anything related to the camera info file in the command line.

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --approximate 0.1 --size 8x6 --square 0.108 right:=/my_stereo/right/image_raw left:=/my_stereo/left/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) with karma: 194 on 2021-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2